# Stack Overflow changed UI template

Tags: support, design, user-interface

The UI Template of Stack Overflow changed today for me. I don't know that this site changed UI template for all users or each one can customize site for own.

Below image is old template of Stack Overflow

> [image]

and following image is a new template of Stack Overflow .

> [image]

and this is a new template of my profile page:

> [image]

How can I change template of Stack Overflow back to the old version?

Comment: Your statement isn't a question or a suggestion... What can be said about this that you haven't already said? (your 'new' ui looks like the mobile version)

Comment: @David Barker. please see my edit

Comment: Are you emulating a specific user agent? The template loading is the mobile / tablet version of the site.

Comment: You are on the mobile view.  Click "full site" in the footer

Comment: @psubsee2003. thanks. template loaded in mobile version.

Comment: @mehdilotfi it remembers that last view you were on.  So you must have accidentally clicked "mobile" the last time you were on the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a "new UI" or even a change.  You are simply looking at the mobile view of the site.  It is designed for mobile devices that view from the web (not from the ios and android apps), but works just fine on any browser.

To toggle between views, just click the link in the footer.

To get from the full site to the mobile view

> [image: MSO footer with mobile link circled]

And to get from the mobile view to the full site

> [image: MSO Mobile View footer with full site link circled]

The site remembers that last view you were on (storing the setting locally), so if you looked at it last on the same computer and browser in the mobile view then the next time you visit the site it will load the mobile view.